# How do I tell if an object is currently colliding with another object?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I can't figure out how to tell if a `GameObject` is currently colliding with another in Unity. I've looked online and can't find any tutorials or answers that work.

Also, what's the difference between a `Collision` and a `Collider` w.r.t. Unity?

---

My dilemma:

I have a third person controller set up and want it to wall jump. I already have an isGrounded function, I just need to test if I'm hitting anything other than the floor. Otherwise I want it to wall jump backwards.

I've already tried:

```
if (this.OnCollisionEnter){
     ...
}

if (Collider.OnCollisionEnter){
     ...
}
```

But it did not work. I now tried:

```
function OnCollisionStay(){
   Debug.Log("Collision");
}
```

I checked my logs, console and still can't find anything.

Comment: This is a different question now. I'd suggest choosing an answer to your original question and posting another with more information for the new issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The function `MonoBehavior.OnCollisionStay()` ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html)) is called every frame for every collider that is touching another collider there are also `OnCollisionEnter()` ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)) and `OnCollisionExit()` ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html)) for similar behavior at the start and end of contact.  If you want to do something while your object is being collided with, put that function in a script on that object and put your code in there.
2. A Collider is the object that does the colliding.  The Collision is the event/data that tells you about the collision.  Some explanation can be found [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-SphereCollider.html) and other places in the Unity docs.

Comment: Could you give an example of this in use? I tried adding `if (this.OnCollisionStay())` but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to implement a function called `OnCollisionStay` that contains the code you want executed every frame your object is colliding with something.  See the link I provided ([here it is again](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html)) for an example implementation.

Comment: Ok, I tried to use OnCollisionStay(){ Debug.Log ("Collision"); }, I played the game, ran into some walls, but still couldn't find anything in my console or logs. Am I still using it the wrong way?

Comment: In order to answer that, I'd need to know more about your project setup.  Is the function itself set up as a proper function in whatever scripting language you're using?  Is it in a script that is on an object that has a collider on it?  Is that collider not a trigger?  Does it follow the considerations mentioned on the last of the links I provided above ([this one](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-SphereCollider.html))?  Etc?

Comment: I'm using javascript, in the 3rd person controller script. I have a character controller on my main character. I don't see why it shouldn't work. I've already tested other functions on it and they worked fine.

Comment: The 3rd Person Controller is not (and does not have) a Collider.  It's a different type of object.  As such, `OnCollisionStay` won't work.  Now that we know this, you probably want the `CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit` function which is called when your Controller hits another Collider ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Based on Unity script reference, [Collision](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collision.html) is a class representing all the information about a collision. It's a parameter passed to `Collider.OnCollisionEnter`, `Collider.OnCollisionStay` and `Collider.OnCollisionExit` events. [Collider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.html) on the other hand is everything that has a physical representation.

So if you want to know whether an object is colliding with any other object in the game, you have to define a *collider* for both of them, and implement [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) event for the object you are interested in.

Comment: Could you give an example of this in use? I tried adding `if (this.OnCollisionStay())` but that didn't work.

Comment: @CharlesL did you even try clicking on any of the links I provided?

Comment: Ok, I tried to use `OnCollisionEnter(){ Debug.Log ("Collision"); }`, I played the game, ran into some walls, but still couldn't find anything in my console or logs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that at least one of the colliding objects have a non-kinematic rigidbody attached? It did the trick for me.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html